# How to keep only words with specific text between in Regex?

Tags: html, regex, parsing, text

i want to keep only words contain specific text between in my document and give separator for each word. For Example:

Before:

```
4Sampledocument test suct.doc hxtp://domain.com/AB/sample.doc ON tuesday 2 A.M
2Sampledocus test sub.doc hxtp://domain.com/EA/samples.doc ON monday 1 A.M
4Sampledocssss test suect.doc hxtp://domain.com/LW/simple.doc ON wednesday 5 P.M
2Ssjxiw92 test ssct.doc hxtp://domain.com/LC/bro.doc ON friday 8 A.M
```

After:

```
hxtp://domain.com/AB/sample.doc|hxtp://domain.com/EA/samples.doc|hxtp://domain.com/LW/simple.doc|hxtp://domain.com/LC/bro.doc
```

| = separator

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: umm maybe i can done this with PHP but i want to know how to do this with regex

Comment: Do you mean you want to do it with one regex replace operation? I think it is quite enough to just split the string with space, take the 4th elements of the arrays and join with `|`. Or you can use a regex to extract the hxtp links and then join them.

Comment: @WidigdoDimasPratama : Can you paste what you have done with PHP?

Comment: Just note that it cannot be done with a pure single regex replace operation since you will still be left with leading and trailing `|`s. You will have to trim them all from the start and end. Otherwise, you'd need a monstrous regex with `preg_replace_callback`. Look, [it already looks bad when you just replace all but the strings you need](http://ideone.com/4cFKsr).

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a line break in the last line, the best bet using a regex replace is as follows. But there will be trailing pipe symbol which you need to remove.

Assuming you are using PHP

```
preg_replace('/.*?(hxtp:.+?)\s+.*\s+/im', '$1|', $full_string);
```

OR

You can loop through each line and parse the hxtp urls only and then implode using `|`

```
preg_match('/.*?(hxtp:.+?)\s+.*/', $line_string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve the result is to find all urls and implode them into one string, although it needs a little bit of extra PHP-Code

Also assuming you are using PHP:

```
$strings = …; // Your text before

// Match each url
preg_match_all('/.*(\S{4,}\:\/\/.+\.doc)\S*/', $strings, $matches);
echo implode("|", $matches[1]);  // Concat
```